# Error on get/set data with firebase and arduinoESP8266 library

Tags: firebase, arduino, esp8266

I can get/set data with firebaseESP8266 library, but i get this error message:

..........
Conectado a MOVISTAR_F5A0

IP: 192.168.1.2

data type mismatch, "Could not parse auth token.

data type mismatch, "Could not parse auth token.

...

My code:

```
#include <FirebaseESP8266.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

// Constantes de configuracion Firebase
#define FIREBASE_HOST "iot-sd-arduino.firebaseio.com"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "private-api-key"

// Constantes de configuracion Conexión Wifi
#define WIFI_SID "MOVISTAR_F5A0"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "X2PUjHxU2UmjcY9XUr3H"

FirebaseData firebaseData;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  // Inicializando pines
  iotHome.init();

  // IP Configuracion
  IPAddress staticIP(192, 168, 1, 9);
  IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 1, 1);
  IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
  IPAddress dns(8, 8, 8, 8);

  //Conexion a WIFI
  WiFi.config(staticIP, subnet, gateway, dns);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SID, WIFI_PASSWORD);

  // Tiempo de espera
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  // Datos de conexión 
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Conectado a ");
  Serial.println(WIFI_SID);
  Serial.print("IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
  Firebase.reconnectWiFi(true);

}

void loop() {
  delay(1000);
  if (Firebase.getInt(firebaseData, "/test/led")) {

    if (firebaseData.dataType() == "int") {
      Serial.println(firebaseData.intData());
    }

  } else {
    Serial.println(firebaseData.errorReason());
  }
```

Firebase database:

[image: Firebase database]

Some idea to solve this?

Comment: You've defined `FIREBASE_AUTH`.  What could "Could not parse auth token" mean?

Comment: Oh right. Thank's.